# nextval on sequence returns all nextval values for all table rows in typeORM on postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nextval

I have a sequence in postgreSQL database, and when I run `NEXTVAL(sequence_name)` query inside pgAdmin 4 it returns only one value that is correct.
However inside NestJS project that's bootstrapped with TypeORM when I run `this.repo.createQueryBuilder().select("NEXTVAL(sequence_name)").execute()`
It returns array of objects with all next values generated.

Example: If I have 500 rows inside the table, it will return 500 NEXTVAL values for some reason.

I've tried my best to find a solution online, but no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: so limit ot to the one you want, we can't tell if you want the first or the tens. also souldthe not ne an order ti thenexval?

Comment: @nbk you're right.

Comment: It sounds as if your obfuscation layer turns that into `select nextval('...') from some_table` - but which table does it use? You should try to find the reaons why it thinks a table is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple, thanks @nbk for the comment.
This was a solution:

```js
this.repo
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .where('id = (select MAX(id) FROM table_name)')
      .select("nextval('sequence_name")
      .getRawOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficient alternatives that don't need to go through select on a specific table:

```js
const [{ id }] = await dataSource.query("SELECT NEXTVAL('users_id_seq') AS id");
```

OR

```js
const [{ id }] = await userRepository.query("SELECT NEXTVAL('users_id_seq') AS id");
```

**NOTE:** When using `select` from `createQueryBuilder`, you are not just getting the next value in the sequence, you are actually bringing a next value to each row of the select in this table (Repository), that is, it is a column in the select.